# Jquery issues with the on method

Tags: jquery, events, methods

Hy, i have a form in witch i have some select boxes, i use a small and easy little jquery plugin to help me style them.

```
$.fn.extend({
customSelect : function(options) {

  if(!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version>6)){
  return this.each(function() {

        var outerClass = options.customClass,
            innerClass = options.customClass_inner;

        var currentSelected = $(this).find(':selected');
        var html = currentSelected.html();
        if(!html){ html='&nbsp;'; }
        $(this).after('<span class="customStyleSelectBox"><span class="customStyleSelectBoxInner">'+html+'</span></span>').css({position:'absolute', opacity:0,fontSize:$(this).next().css('font-size')});
        var selectBoxSpan = $(this).next();
        var selectBoxWidth = parseInt($(this).width()) - parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-left')) -parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-right'));         
        var selectBoxSpanInner = selectBoxSpan.find(':first-child');
        selectBoxSpan.css({display:'inline-block'});
        selectBoxSpanInner.css({width:selectBoxWidth, display:'inline-block'});
        var selectBoxHeight = parseInt(selectBoxSpan.height()) + parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-top')) + parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-bottom'));
        $(this).height(selectBoxHeight).change(function(){
        selectBoxSpanInner.text($(this).find(':selected').text()).parent().addClass('changed');
        }); 
  });
  }
}
});
$('select').customSelect();
```

And it's ok, it works great, the problem is that i also have a button which if you click on ads more and more select boxes, as many as you want.(Never mind why :P)
These select boxes are created also with the help of jquery so i'm adding it dynamically to the dom.

So my problem is that these new select boxes of course don't inherit the style, i know that it's because i add them later to the dom, but who can i make them inherit with the help of the on method?

Thank you, for any help!

Comment: I don't know what version of jQuery you're using, but it seems worth noting that [`$.browser` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call again

```
$('select.newSelect').customSelect();
```

after you add the new select to the DOM. Be careful to add a peculiar class so that your customSelect() code applies only to newly added elements, otherwise you attach events twice. Ore you could generalize the plugin so that it doesn't attach events twice but that's more difficult (hint use `.data()` )

To avoid doing strange things if you call `$('select.newSelect').customSelect();` you could do

```
  if(!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version>6)){
  return this.each(function() {

  if($(this).data('customSelectApplied') !== ''){
        // whe already attached the custom functionality here
        return;
    }else{
        //continue as usual
        $(this).data('customSelectApplied', true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicola Peluchetti , but the problem with that is that it messes up my first select  box, i mean it creates another one, because of course i call the function again

Comment: @Mr.Sam you must add a custom class to your newly added select box or change the plugin

Comment: i see, but i cant imagine what would happen if someone would generate a lot of select boxes

Comment: @Mr.Sam i edited my answerto show how you could getaround that

Comment: hey sorry for this late response but could you please tell me what 'customSelectApplied' means in your code... i mean to what do you refer to with that ? thanks

Comment: @Mr.Sam it's just something that tells me: this DOM element has already been treated, leave it alone. It could be any unique identifier, i choose that becuase it sounded like your plugin

Comment: @Nicole Peluchetti yes, sorry, i'm really really tired :) so for a moment i didn't understand what you meant, but i understand know and it's working perfectly, thanks a lot !!! And have a nice day!

Comment: @Mr.Sam don't worry if you don't understand something always ask for explanation, otherwise you never learn :)

Comment: @Mr.Sam How can you accept an answer and not upvote it? Nicola, get my upvote! **+1**

Answer (score 0):

The `on` function won't help you here. just call that function every time you add new elemenes:

```
$("<select id="aaa">").appendTo('#foo').customSelect();
```

---

If you want to grap new "select"s in one query:
Do this on DOM ready:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').customSelect().addClass('old');
});
```

And later on

```
$('select:not(.old)').customSelect().addClass('old');
```

---

**You can also change the plugin** to add that class and ignore elements with the `old` class:

```
$.fn.extend({
customSelect : function(options) {

  if(!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version>6)){
  return this.filter(':not(.old)').each(function() { // <==== ====== ===== ====== ===
        $(this).addClass('old'); // <==== ====== ===== ===== ====
        var outerClass = options.customClass,
            innerClass = options.customClass_inner;

        var currentSelected = $(this).find(':selected');
        var html = currentSelected.html();
        if(!html){ html='&nbsp;'; }
        $(this).after('<span class="customStyleSelectBox"><span class="customStyleSelectBoxInner">'+html+'</span></span>').css({position:'absolute', opacity:0,fontSize:$(this).next().css('font-size')});
        var selectBoxSpan = $(this).next();
        var selectBoxWidth = parseInt($(this).width()) - parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-left')) -parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-right'));         
        var selectBoxSpanInner = selectBoxSpan.find(':first-child');
        selectBoxSpan.css({display:'inline-block'});
        selectBoxSpanInner.css({width:selectBoxWidth, display:'inline-block'});
        var selectBoxHeight = parseInt(selectBoxSpan.height()) + parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-top')) + parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css('padding-bottom'));
        $(this).height(selectBoxHeight).change(function(){
        selectBoxSpanInner.text($(this).find(':selected').text()).parent().addClass('changed');
        }); 
  });
  }
}
});
```

Then you simply use it like this:

```
$('select').customSelect();
```

And it will ignore "old" `<select>`s.

Comment: Thank's but actually i was hoping someone could tell me how can i proceed when i add new elements to the dom, in this case new form elements, and make them all inherit anything that i added before appending them. Because i have more than just select boxes i have a hole user field where there are text inputs, select boxes, and so on... and all these elements would need to inherit stuff. So i'm looking for an answer where i can make them inherit, is that possible ?

Comment: @Mr.Sam. then the answer is simple. NO. **:)**

Comment: @Mr.Sam. But updating the plugin like I showed you can be helpful, is it?

Comment: Thanks, i think your right, i was searching a lot on the net and i couldn't find anything useful :)